# How to convert a string to integer or float if possible in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, type-conversion, integer

I have the following dictionary:

```
param = {'lgb__boosting_type': 'dart',
 'lgb__colsample_bytree': '0.7135948579099038',
 'lgb__feature_fraction': '0.98283890190338',
 'lgb__learning_rate': '0.041712347301680976',
 'lgb__max_depth': '3',
 'lgb__metric': 'rmse',
 'lgb__min_data_in_leaf': '90',
 'lgb__num_leaves': '55',
 'lgb__objective': 'binary',
 'lgb__reg_lambda': '0.013449050509130145',
 'lgb__subsample': '0.8473591109865588'}
```

Now I want to convert the key values of the dictionary to integer or float (integer preferred over float type) and otherwise it should be kept as a string.

My proceedings thus far:

```
    def int_or_fl(value):
        try:
            value = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            value = int(value)
            except ValueError:
                None

 param = {key:int_or_fl(items) for key,items in param.items()}
```

But I figured you cannot raise an except command inside in another except command.

Comment: try adding another `try` before the `value = int(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `try` block after the first `except`.

```py
def int_or_fl(value):
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            value = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return value
```

If you want to avoid nested `try-except`, you can do the following:

```py
def int_or_fl(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```py
import re
re_int = re.compile(r'\d+$')
re_float = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+$')

def is_int(val):
    return bool(re_int.match(val))
def is_float(val):
    return bool(re_float.match(val))

def int_or_float(val):
    if is_int(val):
        return int(val)
    if is_float(val):
        return float(val)
    return val
```